# Suppose that g is the inverse function of a differentiable function f and G(x) =$\frac{-4}{g^2(x)}$ ....

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Problem :

Suppose that g is the inverse function of a differentiable function f and G(x) =$\frac{-4}{g^2(x)}$ If f(5) =3 and $f'(5) =\frac{1}{125}$ then find $G'(3)$

My approach :

f(5)=5 $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(3)=5$

$\therefore g(3) = 5$

Please suggest how to proceed further as not getting any clue further , please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is the inverse function of $f$, $$g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$$

Hence, we have that $$f\{g(x)\}=x$$ and $$f'\{g(x)\}\cdot g'(x)=1$$

Given that, $f(5)=3$ and $f'(5)=\frac{1}{125}$.

Thus we can write that $$f\{g(3)\}=3  \Rightarrow g(3)=5$$ and $$f'\{g(3)\}\cdot g'(3)=1  \Rightarrow g'(3)=125$$

Now $G(x)=-\frac{4}{g^2(x)}$

Hence we have that $G'(x)=\frac{8}{g^3(x)}\cdot g'(x)$

Thus, we have that $$G'(3)=\frac{8}{g^3(3)}\cdot g'(3)=\frac{8}{125}\cdot 125=\color{red}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

- Using the relation $g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$, differentiate to obtain $f'(x)\cdot g'(f(x)) = 1$ for all $x$. This will be useful to determine $g'(3) = g'(f(5))$.
- Differentiate the expression of $G$ to get $G'(x)$ as a function of $g'(x)$ and $g(x)$.
- Combine both (your knowledge of $g'(3)$ and of $g(3)$) to conclude on the value of $G'(3)$.